# AjaxControlToolkit.dll 1.0.10123.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

which .Net Framework version is support this version of (AjaxControlToolkit.dll (1.0.10123.0)) and which is not?

i have confusion about this, i m using visual studio 2008 Pro .Net Framework 3.5 and when i add the AjaxControlToolkit.dll version (1.0.10123.0) to bin folder then the ajaxcontrolstoolkit is work fine in my project but when i replace it with  AjaxControlToolkit.dll version(3.5.60919.0) then it does not give any response and by default when i add any ajax control to my web form then it is automatically replace the version(1.0.10123.0) with the version(3.5.60919.0) but it does not work with the version(3.5.60919.0).

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project and try to install as below

you can follow this [install steps](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx). you need to download AjaxToolKit for .net 3.5 from [Here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/105897). After you add the ajaxtools to Visual Studio Toolbox, drag and drop the AjaxToolkit Script Manager to Your page. Don't use default script manager control